# Querying XML doc with Excel VBA

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2003, xpath, vba

I'm building a list of nodes I need to load from XML document using SelectNodes(xpath):

```
Set oNodeList = xmldoc.selectNodes("//Object/Property[@Name='Group' and Value='True']")
```

and looping thru the nodes:

```
For Each curNode In oNodeList
  Set nAttr = curNode.parentNode.Attributes
  If (nAttr.getNamedItem("Seq").nodeValue = "abc") Then
'  additional processing
  End If
Next
```

Additional processing involves looping thru child nodes of curNode. I was wondering if it's possible in build yet another nodeList using selectNodes which would select child nodes of curNode that meet particular criteria. The key point that xpath should start looking from the current node.

How can I do that?

Comment: documentation isn't clear. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220790(v=office.11).aspx it looks like you can call `selectNodes` method only for a `Document` class, but then in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212478(v=office.11).aspx there is a `selectNodes` method listed linked to the same documentation page. So, it's not posible to tell how `selectNodes` defines the context node. You could try calling this method from `curNode`. Also, you are performing some filtering inside `For Each` that looks like it could be done in the first XPath expression. Clarify that.

Comment: @Alejandro: Filtering in the For Each is what I'm doing now and of course it works but the code looks ugly. It would be much better if I could Xpath from current node.

I know I could do it by adding [position()=nnn] to the original query (where nnn is curNode index) but again, it's ugly. I'm looking for xpath starting from current node!

Answer (score 1):

Alejandro, thank you! It seems like

```
curNode.Selectnodes("child::*")
```

does the trick!

Comment: I'm glad it helps you. Do note that `*` is a short form of `child::*`